# Interpretation of Prolog's operator in an exercise

Tags: prolog

I have the following exercise about natural language in Prolog:

> Implement the following two operators **has** and **of** in such a way that with phrases like:
>   **peter has car of john** answers to questions such as: **Who has What of X**

Now, I know that in English language this sound bad because in English we usually say: "peter has john's car", but I am Italian and I have tried to translate the Italian request in English.
I hope the concept is however clear.

So I have found the following Prolog solution, saved in a file:

```
:-op(200,xfx,has).
:-op(100,xfx,of).

peter has car of john.
```

After that I consult this file in Prolog shell and I can perform the following operations:

> **?- peter has car of john.**
>
> **true.**

Or:

> **?- X has Y of Z.**
>
> **X = peter,**
>
> **Y = car,**
>
> **Z = john.**

Great, it work, but I have not so clear how it work and I have some questions about the **operator priority**:

**has** operator have 200 as **priority** value.
**of** operator have 100 as **priority** value.

Referring to the phrase: **peter has car of john** so it means that Prolog first evaluate this part of the sentence: **car of john** (because of operator have lower priority respect has operator) and, if it is true, then it evaluate: **pater has (result of the previous evalutatuion).**

In a few words, I can interpret the original sentence in this way:

**peter has (car of john)**

Is it correct?

An other question is related to the operator's typology.

In my solution I use the **xfx** typology for both operators because in this kind of sentences I have no problems related to potential ambiguity with several operators having the same precedence (as in the case: **a - b - c** in which the operator - must have the form **yfx**)

My question is: **Can I obtain the same result using xfy and\or yfx mixing in some way on my has and of operators?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it correct?
>   yes.

`xfx` means that the operator 'dominates' upon its branches, while `xfy` or `yfx` stand for 'list construction', in sense that allow chaining expressions of *same* priority.

With your phrase, you're using the correct op declaration, but you could do with other associativity specifiers, if you see necessity.

I see a possible usage of xfy for `of`, like 'peter has car of john of mary`.
After

```
:- op(100, xfy, of).
:- op(200, xfx, has).
```

I get

```
?- write_canonical(peter has car of john of mary).
has(peter,of(car,of(john,mary)))
true.
```

Comment: Tnx so much !!! Now it appear me more clear about the possible use of xfy form in of operator. Now I will read more about the write_canonical on the documentation. Tnx so much