# Why does Prolog operator definitions have xfx?

Tags: prolog, operators, syntactic-sugar, iso-prolog

For languages such as Java and C which allow [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) with operators, i.e. infix, they use [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity).

Prolog also uses associativity:
left-associative - yfx
right-associative - xfy

but why is there xfx?

The only thing I have found on the internet giving any more clarity is

> xfx means that the operator 'dominates' upon its branches, while xfy
>   or yfx stand for 'list construction', in sense that allow chaining
>   expressions of same priority.

from: [Interpretation of Prolog's operator in an exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15689568/1243762) by [CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874024/capellic)

If the answer can include examples where xfx is needed because xfy and yfx fail/don't have meaning, that would be appreciated.

For Prolog reference: [The Prolog Built-in Directive op](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/cs9414/notes/prolog/op.html)

As [false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false) notes:

> Please note that the operators you give in above link
>   differ from both the standard and SWI! They are outdated by at least
>   10 years. As an example, it should be `current_op(200,fy,-)`.

After reading the two current answers by [CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19935954/1243762) and [false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19936849/1243762) it became clear that
non-associative was the key word to locating more relevant information. So [Operator associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) now make more sense with regards to xfx when paying attention to non-associative section.

Comment: "associativity" describes only how the operator relates to other operators , it describes nothing about the difference in the nature of the operands .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *specifier of an operator* denotes the class (prefix, infix, postfix) and associativity of an operator.

`xfx` means that the operator does not permit any form of associativity. In other words: it does not nest with operators of the same priority. However, it does still nest with operators of a lower priority.

The largest part of such operators are predicates of arity two that are used for comparison-like meaning and where nesting would have - at least - an entirely different meaning than what the predicate is about. They are all located at priority 700: High enough to allow all arithmetic operators to work without bracketing ; low enough to work with control constructs and related meta-predicates that expect goals as arguments. Think of `(\+)/1`, `(;)/2`, `(',')/2`.

Consider `=<`: If you want to state that `X` is between 1 and 3 you cannot write `1 =< X =< 3` because neither `(1 =< X) =< 3` nor `1 =< (X =< 3)` make sense in Prolog. In fact, both would lead to an evaluation error. You have to write `1 =< X, X =< 3`. which means `=<(1, X), =<(X, 3)`.

For some cases it might make sense to nest, think of `(A = B) = P`.  Here, the first `=` is just a functor like any other of arity 2, while the second `=` is the built-in predicate `(=)/2` for equality/unification. But such cases are rare and it is worth highlighting them with an extra pair of round brackets.

Note also that  `:- :- a.` is invalid syntax, because `(:-)/1` again does not nest.

Arithmetic operators are typically left associative since you process them left-to-right like `1+2+4`, first computing `1+2` and only then adding `4`. The notable exception is `(^)/2`: This is so, because  `(X^Y)^Z =:= X^(Y*Z)` whereas `(X^(Y^Z))` denotes a term that cannot be expressed with simpler operators.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Another way to remember: `x` means "no", and `y` means "yes I like to have an operator of my priority on my side".

Comment: "Arithmetic operators are typically left associative since you process them left-to-right" - believing that math is processed left-to-right is a consistent mistake on the part of computer people .  I recently asked a number of advanced mathematicians "do you solve your arithmetic from left-to-right or right-toleft ?"  All of them said right-to-left , 2 of them volunteered the opinion that processing arithmetic right-to-left was a characteristic of the advanced practicioner of mathematics .

Comment: Consider this : ``f : X → Y`` (which is declarativ , xfy) .v.s. this ``h ∘ (g ∘ f)`` (which is procedural , yfx) from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism#Definition  .  You can go far with ``op`` if you abandon the notion of "associativity" and instead consider the ``x`` to be the ``domain``/\``source`` and consider the ``y`` to be the ``codomain/\target`` ;  also sometimes a useful distinction is ``xfy`` is declarativ vs ``yfx`` is procedural .

Comment: "Arithmetic operators are typically left associative since you process them left-to-right" was a quote of an earlier comment ; the earlier comment was deleted subsequent to the appearance of my comment .   The trail we leave behind might be valuable for others to follow . Also , it's okay to be "wrong" .  What message to prolog "Students" , if the "Teachers" are ashamed of being "wrong" ? It's only sycophants and jerks that jump all over you and judge you for being "wrong" , i.e. they like to point their finger and make everyone else feel stupid because then they seem smarter .

Comment: ? This "Arithmetic operators are typically ..." is a quote from my answer above. Do you have any source to substantiate your claim that this does not hold - except anecdotal one? If you are adding a long list of numbers, it seems the natural way to start with the first two.

Comment: sorry false , I (idiot) thought that quote was in a comment that was subsequently deleted in response to my (apparent) ciriticism , my apologies . Other than the reference above   ``h ∘ (g ∘ f)`` I have only the anecdotal .  Not sure from where to obtain something canonical on this topic.  I was taught to simplify from right to left, i.e "let x = 2 , let y = 3 , let z = 4 | w / z =   x * y | w = x * y * z | w = 2 * 3 * 4 | w = 2 * 12 | w = 24" .... is that unusual ? i.e. is it also (or more commonly? ) taught as  "x * y = w / z | x * y * z = w | 2 * 3 * 4 = w | 6 * 4 = w | 24 = w" ?

Comment: Now that I think about it , I was explicitly taught right-to-left evaluation in mathematics. For example, "given y = 3 , x = y - 4 , solve for x" the steps were |1| x = y - 4 |2| x = (-4) + y |3| x = (-4) + 3 |4| x = -1" .  i.e. step |2| is a re-ordering of the terms such that the target of the substitution becomes right-most .  In early grades , failure to demonstrate step 2 was reason for loss of marks .  This is all antecdotal yes . Perhaps an odditity of my school region or whatever . For me it "seems natural" to do mathematics from right to left, maybe a inevitable result of my training .

Comment: "If you are adding a long list of numbers, it seems the natural way to start with the first two" --- as a computer programming task [*36'footnote] , I would naturally start with the first 2 as suggested .  In constrast , as a list of numbers on paper , 1 number to each line , I would start with the rightmost digit , iterate the digits from bottom to top , note the carry at the top and repeat from the bottom .  As a list of numbers all on one line , with the task of solving one operation per line , I would solve the rightmost term thus gradually reducing from right to left .

Comment: [*36'footnote] as a computer programmer before I met prolog .  Consider the following from Clocksin & Mellish pg . 77 ``is_integer(0) . is_integer(X) :- is_integer(Y) , X #= Y + 1 .``  --- the recursive call cause's the Y to be solved first .  I would rewrite the Clocksin & Mellish (not fully logical) as ``(is_integer(X):-(X #= 0 | X #= 1 + Y , is_integer(Y)))`` --- as a set of declarativ statments it reads from left-to-right but as a set of procedural outcomes it reads from right to left .

Comment: sorry for the comment spam but I do find this topic intriguing --- the division operator perhaps provides a definitiv case , division is ``numerator / denominator`` but also ``ordinal / cardinal`` i.e. ``36 apples / 2 bushels`` but not ``2 bushels / 36 apples`` and you need the cardinal (right) before you can have the ordinal (left) (similar to needing a type before having an instance of the type) ... you might state ``18 apples / 1 bushel`` but wouldn't state ``1 apple / 0.055555 bushels`` ... demonstrating that with division the right (bottom) is solved first .

Comment: So effectively you are adding digit-wise right-to-left on paper. Interesting. I learned it left-to-right with carries noted at the end (now I realize that the additional space for carries could be quite large).

Answer (score 2):

For instance, (:-)/2 it's clearly an operator that can used only *once*, because it *separates* the head from the body.

The separation is 'relative', you could have in a rule, for instance

```
my_rule :- assertz((a :- b, c)).
```

Here is the full list of (default) xfx operators from SWI-Prolog

```
?- setof((X,Y), current_op(X,xfx,Y), L), maplist(writeln, L).
200, (**)
700, (<)
700, (=)
700, (=..)
700, (=:=)
700, (=<)
700, (==)
700, (=@=)
700, (=\=)
700, (>)
700, (>=)
700, (@<)
700, (@=<)
700, (@>)
700, (@>=)
700, (\=)
700, (\==)
700, (\=@=)
700, (as)
700, (is)
1200, (-->)
1200, (:-)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'dominates' and 'relative'?

Comment: Were purely descriptive words. I meant 'dominates' because it stays at top of its relative syntax tree, 'relative' was meant to introduce a scope. Parenthesis reset the scope. It's a simple construct, after all.

Comment: @CapelliC "For instance, (:-)/2 it's clearly an operator that can used only once, because it separates the head from the body." .  The interpretation of ':-' as being a function definition such that ``FunctionHead :- FunctionBody`` is certainly the norm but perhaps too limiting for prolog .  An alternate interpretation is that ``:-`` means *syntactic consequence* such that ``AntecedentExpression :- ConsequentExpression`` ... for example ``((foo - X + Y):-(throw(nonimplemented))) . ((bar):-(foo - 3 + chocolate)) . ?- (bar).`` . i.e. ``(foo - X + Y)`` is not a function head .

Comment: @kintalken ":- means **syntactic** consequence" ... or maybe it means **semantic** consequence , or perhaps ``SatisfactionModel :- SatisfactionSentences`` , there are (apparently) lots of potentially applicable interpretations from the broad field of logic .c.f. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2coygw1HT0

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the current status of the prolog standard `op` scene is necessarily a definitive guide to how to use op.  Reduction of each op to these type codes (xf, fx, yfx, etc.) was a brilliant invention, but such an invention is more a product of the zeitgeist than the product of any particular rationale (.i.e. the outcome is not necessarily defined by the intentions of the inventor).

`xfy` is an op that has a source on the left and a target on the right.
`xfx` is an op that has a source on the left and a source on the right.
`yfx` is an op that has a target on the left and a source on the right.

'xfy' is (generally) associated with :

- left-to-right
- top-to-bottom
- domination
- being first
- being declarativ
- being ignorant of the 'yfx'

'xfx' is (generally) associated with:

- judgement of the operands
- comparison of things of equal class
- that's all I have for this weirdo

'yfx' is (generally) associated with:

- right-to-left
- bottom-to-top
- egalitarian
- being last (thus ultimately achieving true domination)
- being procedural
- being tolerant of the shenanigans of the 'xfy'

Note that the following works out because the 'x' and 'y' are partnered throughout :

```
  xfy xfx yfx
```

but in contrast this does not work out:

```
  yfx xfx xfy
```

Some examples (untested, just sketches)...

```
  (term_expansion((_a),(true)):-(asserta(_a))) .
  (term_expansion((_a | _b),(_b)):-(expand_term(_a,_c),asserta(_c))) .

  :-
  (op(10'1200,'xfy',':='))
  ,
  (op(10'1200,'xfx',':~'))
  ,
  (op(10'1200,'yfx',':-'))
  .

  (term_expansion((_a := _b :- _c),(term_expansion(_a,_b):-_c))) .
  (term_expansion((_a :~ _b :- _c),(goal_expansion(_a,_b):-_c))) .
  (term_expansion((_a := _b1 :~ _b2 :- _c),((_a := _b1 :- _c) | (_a :~ _b2 :- _c)))) .
```

In that example the `:-` is `yfx`.  The syntax is `___consequent___ :- ___precedent___` ; the right is the **source** aka the **domain** (thus evaluated first), the left is the **target** aka the **codomain** (thus evaluated second).

In that example the `:~` is `xfx`.  The syntax is `___goal_1___ :~ ___goal_2__`. It corresponds to a goal_expansion.

In that example the `:=` is `xfy`.  The syntax is `___precedent___ := ___consequence__`.  It corresponds to a term_expansion.

```
  :-
  (op(10'700,'xfy','@='))
  ,
  (op(10'700,'xfx','\\='))
  ,
  (op(10'700,'yfx','#='))
  .

  (_x @= _y) :- ('='(_x,_y)) . % .i.e. term equality
  % (_x1 \= _x2)   % prolog builtin, not equal
  % (_y #= _x)   % via clpfd, math is generally simplification/\answer is left
```

The `\=` is, in my opinion, the definitiv example of an `xfx` operator.

The terminology `source | domain, target | codomain`, is from here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism#Definition.

I don't know much about category theory (yet), but I do wonder if the `xfx` has something to do with the `identity morphism`.